# Typescript/Google Maps: how to determine which marker was clicked

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, arrow-functions

I have an array of marker objects `markers`. I then use a for loop to add event listeners to them. However, I can't seem to figure out how to determine WHICH of the markers was clicked.

Here is the code I have now:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) //adds listener to all markers
{
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[i], "click", () =>
  {
    //need to get access to which marker was clicked
    //need to use arrow function to retain proper reference to "this"
  }); 
}
```

I've tried passing arguments to the arrow function, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
for each ( var marker in this.markers ) {
    with( { mark: marker } ) { // <- mark will contain the marker, and keep it all the way
        google.maps.event.addListener( mark, 'click', function() {  
            return mark; // <- this will return the actual marker
        } );
    }
}
```